# copying node_modules to offline computer

Tags: node.js, npm, robocopy

I need to copy a Node.JS project to a computer that will not be connected to the internet. Yes, I know that NPM can create a TarBall, but that is really not appropriate here:

1. It is a windows box
2. It has limited storage

I was wondering if I could just do a recursive copy of all the .js files in node_modules
[NOTE, my node project is very clean, it does not include any .dll or native system access stuff]

E.g.

```
robocopy $source/node_modules $dest/node_modules /S /NFL /TEE /LOG:watson.log /MT:16 *.js *.json *.types
```

which uses 16 threads in RoboCopy to do a full tree copy

```
#robocopy swtiches /S = subdirs, /ETA = estimates, /NFL = don't list files, /MT = number of parallel tasks, /TEE show log on console
#robocopy switches /xd directory exclude /xf file exclude
```

Comment: NPM is capable of generating and installing tarballs (try `npm install your.tar.gz`). Also, copying only the .js files may not work properly for all dependencies...

Comment: Yes, as I said, I knew about npm tarballs, but I really did not want all the other stuff people put in their packages. I have found that grabbing all the json, js, and the two .types files that node wants is working for me. But it is true, if you need DLLs you will have to add more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is working for me. But then, I did not need any fancy dependencies (e.g. DLL files). Works fine at removing lots of stuff in the packages I do not need.